# jQuery focus/blur toggle within same div

Tags: jquery, loops, focus, blur

```
$('#topcontainer input,select').focus(function() {

   $("#square1").animate({"opacity":"1"}, 400);

}).blur(function() {

    $("#square1").animate({"opacity":"0.2"}, 400);

});
```

This is code that works basically. But what happens is that code loops when I shift between different inputs (or select) within same div. When I click on one input square1 change it opacity to 1, and when I transfer on second input which is still in same div container code loops itself, opacity goes to 0.2 and then to 1. Is there a way not to loop it while Im positioned at the same div.

thanks

Comment: Post the markup also. That would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what you want but i guess you should

use jQuery [.stop](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to stop ongoing animation.

```
$('#topcontainer input,select').focus(function() {

   $("#square1").stop().animate({"opacity":"1"}, 400);

}).blur(function() {

    $("#square1").stop().animate({"opacity":"0.2"}, 400);

});
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HsPKC/) . click on any of the controls and then click anywhere else.